# Calling a function from PhantomJS onLoadFinished callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, browser-automation

I started using PhantomJS a few days ago with NodeJS.
I am using this library to integrate with it: https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node.
Everything worked perfectlly but when I tried to continue the flow of my applcation after a page load (from the callback) something went wrong.

```
function doStuff ()
{
    page.open("http://stackoverflow.com/")
        .then(function (status) {
                function responseHandler(status) {
                    console.log("loaded");
                    iAmHere();
                    console.log("Here Again");
                }

                function loginAction() {
                    var btn = document.querySelector("#button");
                    btn.click();
                }

                page.property('onLoadFinished', responseHandler);
                page.evaluate(loginAction)
            }
    );
}


function iAmHere (){
    console.log("iAmHere");
}
```

The #button element triggers some page load, The responseHandler function is called and the output is:

> info: loaded

and the function iAmHere doesn't get called at all and niether the log that follows the call.
What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `iAmHere()` isn't being invoked when the `onLoadFinished` event fires is because the function you provided, `responseHandler`, is actually being executed by the **PhantomJS JavaScript engine**, and not Node.js.

Therefore, it doesn't have access to the `iAmHere()` function, which you defined within your Node.js script.

You could, instead, be notified when the page finishes loading like this:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

var sitepage = null;
var phInstance = null;
phantom.create()
    .then(instance => {
        phInstance = instance;
        return instance.createPage();
    })
    .then(page => {
        sitepage = page;
        return page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/');
    })
    .then(status => {
        console.log(status);

        // Page loaded, do something with it

        return sitepage.property('content');
    })
    .then(content => {
        console.log(content);
        sitepage.close();
        phInstance.exit();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        phInstance.exit();
    });
```